# Where to restore forms size and position from Registry

Tags: c#

I save the forms size and position with this code:

```
    string keyName = string.Format("Software\\{0}\\Position", def.APPNAME);
    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(keyName)) {
        rk.SetValue("width", this.Width.ToString());
        rk.SetValue("height", this.Height.ToString());
        rk.SetValue("left", this.Left.ToString());
        rk.SetValue("top", this.Top.ToString());
        rk.SetValue("windowstate", this.WindowState.ToString());
    }
```

And I try to restore it with this code:

```
    string keyName = string.Format("Software\\{0}\\Position", def.APPNAME);
    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, false)) {
        this.Width = (int)rk.GetValue("width");
        this.Height = (int) rk.GetValue("height");
        this.Left = (int) rk.GetValue("left");
        this.Top = (int) rk.GetValue("top");
    }
```

But I can't figure out where to place it to get it to work. I've tried in the constructor, the forms Load event, the forms OnLoad event and the forms OnCreateControl event.

In the constructor, after InitializeComponent(), I'll get an error saying System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

In the forms Load event, the forms OnLoad event and the forms OnCreateControl event nothing happens.

But if I enter some values directly, it will work:

```
    this.Size = new Size(1000,600);
```

But only if I comment out the restore settings part!

Where should I have the code placed and how do I get the code to work as I want?

Comment: [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kk9bxk9(v=vs.110).aspx) uses the type of the second parameter to determine how to store the data. In this case, you `ToString` making the stored value a string instead of an integer. For the integer values, you could just skip the `ToString` and write an int value.

Comment: I would suggest using appSettings in a app.config for which you can use the Setting designer in VS to store such things rather than the registry, they are after all Application Settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay close attention to `System.InvalidCastException`. You are storing the values as `String`s in the registry, but expecting them to be `int` when reading them.

Would this code work?

```
(int)"600"
```

Of course not.

You should use `Int32.Parse`, `Int32.TryParse`, or `Convert.ToInt32` instead of casting to `int`:

```
object v = rk.GetValue("width");
if (v != null)
{
    //TryParse would be even better.
    this.Width = Int32.Parse((string)v);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. But where is best practice to place the restore code? In the constructor or the Load event?

Comment: I would put it in the Load event, though I don't see much difference.